# How to conserve only "APM events" data in newrelic?

Tags: newrelic

I am looking to find a solution reduce the stored "data ingestion" on newrelic.
My team and I are using this tools only to survey server Apdex and we want to focus only on APM data.

Our problem is it appeared on page "Data management hub / Data ingestion" a huge amount of "Metrics", and the weight of this data will be billed to us, while we do not use it...
Is there a way to not keep the data which does not concern the APM data?

Thanks in advance guys!

Edit 1:

[With newrelic topic recommandation](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/data-ingestion-what-are-metrics/127398/3) and some research, i was able to make a query to retrieve the “Metrics” I want to do not store (& pay) on newrelic.

```sql
SELECT
    rate(sum(GigabytesIngested), 1 day) AS avgGbIngestTimeseries
    FROM NrConsumption
    WHERE productLine='DataPlatform' FACET CASES (
        WHERE usageMetric LIKE '%Metrics%' AS 'Metrics'
    )
    LIMIT 11 TIMESERIES AUTO since 30 days ago
```

I read that is possible to delete this metrics by two ways:

- [drop data using nerdgraph](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/accounts/accounts/data-management/drop-data-using-nerdgraph), but this solution freak me out a lot, because i don’t want to miss any data on production that i’m using and break newrelic tools or stats for current month xD.
- [drop data drop filter rules](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/logs/log-management/ui-data/drop-data-drop-filter-rules), sounds sexiest, but i didn’t undestand if this is applicable on newrelic agent log capture.

Any recommandation on with method to use ?